# Python: Type Error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.4

I'm really stuck, I am currently reading Python - How to automate the boring stuff and I am doing one of the practice projects.

Why is it flagging an error? I know it's to do with the item_total.

```
import sys

stuff = {'Arrows':'12',
     'Gold Coins':'42',
     'Rope':'1',
     'Torches':'6',
     'Dagger':'1', }

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = sum(stuff.values())
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v + '   ' + k)
    a = sum(stuff.values())
    print("Total number of items: " + item_total)

displayInventory(stuff)
```

error i get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Lewis/Dropbox/Python/Function displayInventory p120 v2.py", line 17, in 
>       displayInventory(stuff)
>     File "C:/Users/Lewis/Dropbox/Python/Function displayInventory p120 v2.py", line 11, in displayInventory
>       item_total = int(sum(stuff.values()))
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Your traceback and your posted code don't actually match. Not that the `int()` call matters there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary values are all strings:

```
stuff = {'Arrows':'12',
     'Gold Coins':'42',
     'Rope':'1',
     'Torches':'6',
     'Dagger':'1', }
```

yet you try to sum these strings:

```
item_total = sum(stuff.values())
```

`sum()` uses a starting value, an integer, of `0`, so it is trying to use `0 + '12'`, and that's not a valid operation in Python:

```
>>> 0 + '12'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

You'll have to convert all your values to integers; either to begin with, or when summing:

```
item_total = sum(map(int, stuff.values()))
```

You don't really need those values to be strings, so the *better* solution is to make the values integers:

```
stuff = {
    'Arrows': 12,
    'Gold Coins': 42,
    'Rope': 1,
    'Torches': 6,
    'Dagger': 1,
}
```

and then adjust your inventory loop to convert those to strings when printing:

```
for k, v in inventory.items():
    print(v + '   ' + str(k))
```

or better still:

```
for item, value in inventory.items():
    print('{:12s} {:2d}'.format(item, value))
```

to produce aligned numbers with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: Thank you, so simple now

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `sum` a bunch of strings, which won't work. You need to convert the strings to numbers *before* you try to `sum` them:

```
item_total = sum(map(int, stuff.values()))
```

Alternatively, declare your values as integers to begin with instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

This error produce because you was trying sum('12', '42', ..), so you need to convert every elm to int

```
item_total = sum(stuff.values())
```

By

```
item_total = sum([int(k) for k in stuff.values()])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in line

```
a = sum(stuff.values())
```

and

```
item_total = sum(stuff.values())
```

The value type in your dictionary is `str` and not `int`, remember that `+` is concatenation between strings and addition operator between integers. Find the code below, should solve the error, converting it into int array from a str array is done by mapping

```
import sys

stuff = {'Arrows':'12',
     'Gold Coins':'42',
     'Rope':'1',
     'Torches':'6',
     'Dagger':'1'}

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = (stuff.values())
    item_total = sum(map(int, item_total))
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v + '   ' + k)
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

displayInventory(stuff)
```